# Can I power an NodeMCU trough VIN providing 5v

Tags: esp8266

I have a spb 8266 board, an ESP-12E NodeMCU.
I broke my micro USB.

There's [this](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/) piece of information but my case is unclear:

Can I use the micro usb's 5v to power the board through the VIN or do any solution require more equipment than that ?

(The board only has 3.3V and **no** 5V)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use the micro usb's 5v to power the board through the VIN or do any solution require more equipment than that ?

Yes. That is the pin's purpose.  You can use any voltage from about 4.5V up to 20V, although higher voltages will cause more heat from the on-board 3.3V regulator.

VIN just connects to the 5V of the USB.

Comment: through a diode... On many (all?) ch340g-based nodeMCU, that pin does does something else, I'm not sure what, but it reads about 1.6v when powered by USB, which means we can't use it to power a sensor.

Comment: Stove have a diode on that pin, stone have it on the usb power. Without knowing exactly what model and who made it is impossible to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with the "v3" (Lolin) pcb, USB v5 pin is not directly connected to Vin, but to VU. Vin has a S4 SMD diode (aka Schottky 40V1A 1N5819) between it and the USB v5 pin.